# Why jQuery animate doesn't work with cssHooks?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
$.cssHooks.test = {
    get: function(elem) {
        return $(elem).height();
    },
    set: function(elem, value) {
        $(elem).height(value);
    }
};

$('#test').css('test', '30px');

$('#test').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: 100,
        test: 100
    }, 'slow');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CzkQ8/2/

After click, the width gets to 100px, but the height is still 30px, why?

**Edit**

After carefully reading the docs, I know how to get cssHooks to work with animate.

```
$.fx.step.test = function(fx) {
    $.cssHooks.test.set(fx.elem, fx.now + fx.unit);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CzkQ8/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I think you really need, change the height every time you set the width. `$.cssHooks` is meant to work for existing properties. http://jsfiddle.net/CzkQ8/11/

```
$.cssHooks.width = {
    set: function(elem, value) {
        elem.style.width = elem.style.height = value;
    }
};

$('#test').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: 100
    }, 'slow');
});​
```

The reason your example doesn't work is because animate is not calling `$.css('test', value)` repeatedly, it's calling `$.css('height', value)`

`$.cssHooks` gets called every time you call `$.css(propName, value)` However, animate never calls `$.css('test', value)` that is why it works when youcall `$.css('test', 1000)` yourself;

**@clyfish**
 Your update to your question is not the correct way to do what you are doing. You're trying to

> Add support to animate a custom property `test` and add a hook that is called  every time `$.css('test')` is called

This is what you really should have http://jsfiddle.net/CzkQ8/14/

```
$.cssHooks.test = {       
    get: function(elem) {
        return $(elem).height();
    },
    set: function(elem, value) {
        $(elem).height(value);
    }
};

$.fx.step.test = function(fx) {
    // No need to call the hook itself. A step function is supposed to call 
    // $.css() and that will in turn call the hook
    $(fx.elem).css('test', fx.now + fx.unit);
};

$('#test').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: 100,
        test: 100
    }, 'slow');
});​
```

Hope you understand what I'm trying to show you.

Comment: But $('#test').css('test', '30px') works, is it a jquery bug?

Comment: `$.animate` only works with a subset of CSS properties, it doesn't work on custom CSS properties. Therefore, `$.css('test')` never gets called by `$.animate` Therefore, the answer is that `$.cssHooks` does work with animate as long as you use it as it was meant to be used. The documentation doesn't say anything about `$.animate` working for custom CSS properties http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: see my edit, $.fx.step can get cssHooks to work with animate.

Comment: @clyfish: Remember `$.cssHooks` does work `$.animate` as long you use valid CSS properties. it's `$.animate` that doesn't work with custom CSS properties. Your fix makes `$.animate` work with a custom CSS property called `test`, not all CSS properties. What is the sense of that? What are you trying to achieve? I still think you misunderstand how `$.cssHooks` works, and are misusing it.

Comment: Thank you, I know what you mean.